# How to train two pytorch networks with different inputs together?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I'm totally new to pytorch, so it might be a very basic question. I have two networks that should be trained together.

1. First one takes data as input and returns its embedding as output.
2. Second one takes pairs of embedded datapoints and returns their 'similarity' as output.
3. Partial loss is then computed for every datapoint, and then all the losses are combined.
4. This final loss should be backpropagated through both networks.

How should the code for that look like? I'm thinking something like this:

```
def train_models(inputs, targets):
    network1.train()
    network2.train()
    embeddings = network1(inputs)
    paired_embeddings = pair_embeddings(embeddings)
    similarities = network2(similarities)

    """
        I don't know how the loss should be calculated here.
        I have a loss formula for every embedded datapoint, 
        but not for every similarity.
        But if I only calculate loss for every embedding (using similarites),
        won't backpropagate() only modify network1, 
        since embeddings are network1's outputs
        and have not been modified in network2?
    """        

    optimizer1.step()
    optimizer2.step()
    scheduler1.step()
    scheduler2.step()
    network1.eval()
    network2.eval()
```

I hope this specific enough. I'll gladly share more details if necessary. I'm just so inexperienced with pytorch and deep learning in general, that I'm not even sure how to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use single optimizer for this purpose, and even pass different learning rate for each network.

```py
optimizer = optim.Adam([
    {'params': network1.parameters()},
    {'params': network2.parameters(), 'lr': 1e-3}
], lr=1e-4)

# ...

loss = loss1 + loss2
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: thanks, I'll keep that in mind. What I'm having more troubles with, though, is how to set up the loss.